# How to use testng annotations in java

Tags: java, annotations, testng, selendroid

## My code

```
public class Test{

  @BeforeTest
  public void create_user throws Exception (){

  }

  @Test
    public void user_actions throws Exception (){

  }

  @AfterTest
  public void delete_user throws Exception(){

  }

}
```

Above is my test class. If i get any error in `create_user()`, currently its throws `Exception` and ran out of the test case.

But i need `delete_user()` should be executed irrespective of any error in `create_user()` or `user_actions()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `@AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)`.

From the [TestNG doc](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations):

> For after methods (afterSuite, afterClass, ...): If set to true, this configuration method will be run even if one or more methods invoked previously failed or was skipped.

Answer (score 0):

If the test exception is expected you can use @expected to inform the test about the exception which would ensure calling delete_user. 
If it is an adhoc exception having finally block to delete_user is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

If the test method should expect an exception, use the following annotation:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions=<your exceptions here>)
public void user_actions throws Exception (){
    // 
}
```

If the test method throws an unexpected exception, I would recommend to review your test setup/method.